# How to tell Liquibase to ignore a db.changelog*.xml?

Tags: unit-testing, liquibase

I would like liquibase to create a set of unit testing functions ONLY if the database is being created in a DEV environment.

I know I could create a "changeset" tag with a "context" attribute for every unit test function but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

What would be ideal is using "context" with the "includeAll" tag, like:

```
<includeAll path="./sql/UnitTest/" context="dev" />
```

but sadly that is not supported.

OR since I have several changelogs:

```
db.changelog.xml
   include db.changelog-tables.xml
   include db.changelog-functions.xml
   ...
   include db.changelog-unit_test_functions.xml
```

If I could tell LiquiBase to skip running "db.changelog-unit_test_functions.xml" based on a command line parameter that would also work.

However, the "context" attribute is not allowed in the "include" element.

```
<include file="./sql/db.changelog-unit-test.xml" context="dev" />
```

I tried to attach a "preconditions" test to db.changelog-unit-test.xml but that fails ALL db.changelogs execution.

Does anyone have any clever ideas on how I can avoid writing a granular db.changelog-unit-test.xml?

Thanks!

Comment: context in `include` or `includeAll` doesn't work? What version of liquibase are you using? by documentation [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Context in `include` or `includeAll` is working from 3.5
Pay attention to your xsd definition in your file - you need to have at lease http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd there, otherwise your file will not be validate even when running version newer then 3.5